# Play Services crash with obfuscated trace

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, android-pendingintent

I am currently investigating a tricky issue which I am facing with my application. It seems my app (heavily relying on **Location**, but also using **Google Analytics** and **GCM Task Service**) is causing Google Play Services to crash. (Popup appears rather frequently sometimes, but then disappears again for hours - days).

I cannot really track down where the issue is coming from also not how to reproduce it, two things I know:

1. It is my app - disabling it, will fix the crashes
2. If I disable the location part of my app, the crashes stop.

I managed to grab a **stacktrace** at some point:

```
/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: lowpool[0]
                                               Process: com.google.android.gms.persistent, PID: 29021
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
                                                   at aipa.a(:com.google.android.gms:1053)
                                                   at ailk.c(:com.google.android.gms:252)
                                                   at aill.run(:com.google.android.gms:1047)
                                                   at kmo.run(:com.google.android.gms:450)
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                   at kqt.run(:com.google.android.gms:17)
                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I am requesting Location Updates in a **separate process** using the PendingIntent way to do so:

```
if (mTrackIntent == null) {
                    Intent trackIntent = LocationHandlerReceiver.create(getApplicationContext());
                    mTrackIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), REQUEST_CODE_TRACK, trackIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                }

PendingResult<Status> statusPendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.flushLocations(mGoogleApiClient);
            statusPendingResult.setResultCallback(result -> {
                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mTrackIntent);
                    //noinspection MissingPermission
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, mTrackIntent);


                } else {
                    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                        DebugUtils.showDebugToastOnUiThread(getApplicationContext(), "DEV: Requesting location updates.. failed: " + result.getStatusMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Those updates I receive quite successfully here:

```
public static class LocationHandlerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static Intent create(Context context) {
    Intent trackIntent = new Intent(context, LocationHandlerReceiver.class);
    trackIntent.setAction(ACTION_TRACK);
    return trackIntent;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Received location intent: \n" + IntentUtil.dumpIntent(intent));
        try {
            if (LocationAvailability.hasLocationAvailability(intent)) {
                LocationAvailability locationAvailability = LocationAvailability.extractLocationAvailability(intent);
                Crashlytics.log(Log.INFO, TAG, "Could not process location result, Location unavailable: " + locationAvailability.isLocationAvailable());
            } else if (LocationResult.hasResult(intent)) {

                // process results

            } else {
                Crashlytics.logException(new Exception("Could not log location because of null Location"));
            }
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not process location result", throwable);
            Crashlytics.logException(new IllegalStateException("Could not process location result", throwable));
        }
    }
}
```

Some background (app - build.gradle):

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25 //24
    compileSdkVersion 25 //24
}

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1'
```

I tried looking up the stack trace and could not find anything relevant. Has anyone ever encountered a similar issue? Any ideas on how I could track down the reason maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using other versions of Play services and still encountered same error

Comment: I had the same error for weeks at least, with probably 3 - 4 incremental versions of play services. The difficulty to reproduce it makes it nearly impossible though to rule that out.

Comment: Just fyi. The issue has not been seen anymore since the 10.x releases of google play